# Operator '&&' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Task<bool>' and 'bool'

Tags: c#

I have the following:

```
val.MustAsync((x, c) => 
  cnx.Langs.AnyAsync(y => y.Code == x) && set.Langs.Contains(x))
```

But I get the error:

```
Operator '&&' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Task<bool>' and 'bool'
```

How can I use both conditions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to `await` the task:

```cs
(await cnx.Langs.AnyAsync(y => y.Code == x)) && set.Langs.Contains(x)
```